# django rest framework - using viewsets

Tags: python, routes, view, django-rest-framework

I read about the viewsets in django, but haven't fully understood everything..

When using  a viewset in django, for example -

```
class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.

    Additionally we also provide an extra `highlight` action.
    """
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    @detail_route(renderer_classes=[renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer])
    def highlight(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        snippet = self.get_object()
        return Response(snippet.highlighted)
```

and **Routing** is like this

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'snippets', views.SnippetViewSet)
```

In the comments in the View they say - "This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,`update` and `destroy` actions."

**EDIT:::**

```
 @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def register(request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username = serializer.init_data['username'],
                password = serializer.init_data['password'],
            )

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

- How do I access each one of those methods? and How do I access the highlight method?
- The url registered in the router is /snippets. Do I do snippets/create? or snippets/delete?
- What does the ModelViewSet actually does to the url structure?

Comment: It may help you https://learnbatta.com/blog/viewsets-in-django-rest-framework-83/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You access those actions by specifying the corresponding HTTP method, which is a core idea in [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).  Namely, using the HTTP methods to do what their name implies.

- `GET /snippets/` - list the snippet objects
- `POST /snippets/` with POST data - create a new object
- `PATCH /snippets/` with data - create a new object
- `GET /snippets/42` - retrieve object with a primary key of 42
- `PUT/PATCH /snippets/42` - update object with the primary key of 42
- `DELETE /snippets/42` - delete object with the primary key of 42

To see all the generated and inferred URL regexes, put [Django in debug mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#debug) and issue a request to an invalid URL.  It will print out something like:

```
Using the URLconf defined in my_app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^ ^$ [name='api-root']
^ ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)$ [name='api-root']
^ ^AltEmail/$ [name='altemail-list']
^ ^AltEmail/\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)$ [name='altemail-list']
^ ^AltEmail/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='altemail-detail']
^ ^AltEmail/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)$ [name='altemail-detail']
[...]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. so lets say I have a UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet), so I'll have only the GET /users (list) and GET /users/42 (User number 42)?

Comment: Pretty much.  One more tiny detail.  You can add a suffix to override the `content-type` of your request header. e.g. `/users/.json` or `/users/42/.json`.  You'll see that in regexes as `(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)`.

Comment: got it. one more thing, if I add a detail_route decorator (see my edited question), to access this method will be users/register/?

Comment: I haven't used [that specific feature](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions), but per this snippet `^users/{pk}/set_password/$`, perhaps you can only access it via the primary key?  Anyways, I don't know.  Best to just try it out :-D